# scala: empty constructor for a class with type tag

Tags: scala

Consider the following definition for a class.

```
case class DiscreteProperty[T <: AnyRef](
  name: String,
  sensor: T => String,
  range: Option[List[String]]
)(implicit val tag: ClassTag[T]) extends TypedProperty[T, String] {

  /// some stuff here 
}
```

I am getting the following error at some point:

```
Can't instantiate 'edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.saul.datamodel.property.features.discrete.DiscreteProperty$$anon$2':
```

I suppose this is because the class doesn't have an empty constructor. How can I define an empty constructor for this class? I tried the following but it is giving me the following error:

```
  def this() {
    this("funnyName", T => "" ,Option(List()))
  }
```

And none of these work:

```
  def this[T]() {
    this("funnyName", T => "" ,Option(List()))
  }
```

or

```
  def this[T]() {
    this[T]("funnyName", T => "" ,Option(List()))
  }
```

Any ideas how to create an empty constructor for this class with type tag?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're not including the implicit parameter in any of your empty constructors. You're treating the primary constructor as having the signature `(String, T => String, Option[List[String]])`, but that's not quite right. In fact, it's `(String, T => String, Option[List[String]])(ClassTag[T])` (note the `ClassTag` parameter).

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, since the implicit parameter would be retrieved from the scope of that constructor. However, ClassTag is a bit special - it is filled in at compile time with the ClassTag corresponding to whatever your `T` is. The problem in each of those auxiliary constructors is that the `T` is still generic, so the compiler doesn't know which ClassTag to include: there's no implicit parameter available within that scope.

So, how can you fix it? The easiest way is probably to include the implicit parameter in any auxiliary constructors:

```
def this()(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = this("funnyName", T => "", Option(List()))
```

Note that, you don't need to explicitly proved the `ClassTag` to the chained constructor; it's now part of the scope and will be used implicitly. Of course, you can decide to do so explicitly like so:

```
def this()(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = this("funnyName", T => "", Option(List()))(tag)
```